# magnitude of the superposition of plane waves

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

As it has been a good many years since I've done any vector manipulation, some help to jolt my memory would be good.

The two plane waves are

$\vec{E_{1}} = \hat{e_{1}}|\vec{E}_{1}| e^{i(\vec{k}\vec{r} - \omega t)}e^{i\phi_{1}}$

and

$\vec{E_{2}} = \hat{e_{2}}|\vec{E}_{2}| e^{i(\vec{k}\vec{r} - \omega t)}e^{i\phi_{2}}$

where

$\vec{k} = \langle k_{x}, k_{y}, k_{z} \rangle$, $\vec{r} = \langle r_{x}, r_{y}, r_{z} \rangle$.

I want to show that $|\vec{E}|^{2} = |E_{1}|^{2} + |E_{2}|^{2} + 2 |\vec{E}_{1}| |\vec{E}_{2}| cos(\phi)$

The square of the magnitude for $\vec{E}_{1}$ gives
$|\vec{E}_{1}|^{2} = |\vec{E}_{1}| |e^{i(\vec{k}\vec{r} - \omega t)}e^{i\phi_{1}}| = |\vec{E}_{1}| |e^{-(\vec{k}\vec{r} - \omega t)\phi_{1}}|$

and the square of the magnitude for $\vec{E}_{2}$ gives
$|\vec{E}_{2}|^{2} = |\vec{E}_{2}| |e^{i(\vec{k}\vec{r} - \omega t)}e^{i\phi_{2}}| = |\vec{E}_{2}| |e^{-(\vec{k}\vec{r} - \omega t)\phi_{2}}|$

Any further help or hints are appreciated.

Comment: What's $\textbf{E}$ (presumably $\textbf{E}_1+\textbf{E}_2$) and $\phi$?

Comment: @innerproduct It's the sum of the $\vec{E_{1}}$ and $\vec{E_{2}}$ or, more concretely, the sum of two electric field. $\phi$ is a scalar, or a phase delay, in physics speak.

Comment: And $\phi$ is related to $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ somehow?

Comment: @innerproduct $\phi$ is the difference between $\phi_{1}$ and $\phi_{2}$. It is the relative phase between the two waves.

Comment: @innerproduct updated the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer because I don't know how to account for the angle, but hopefully it still helps. For any vector sum $E=E_1+E_2$, we can write

\begin{align}
|E|^2&=\langle E_1+E_2, E_1+E_2 \rangle=\langle E_1, E_1+E_2 \rangle +\langle E_2, E_1+E_2 \rangle\\
&=\langle E_1, E_1 \rangle+\langle E_1, E_2 \rangle +\langle E_2, E_1 \rangle +\langle E_2, E_2 \rangle\\
&=|E_1|^2 + |E_2|^2+2\langle E_1, E_2 \rangle\\
&=|E_1|^2 + |E_2|^2+2|E_1| |E_2| \cos(\phi),
\end{align}

where $\phi$ is the angle between $E_1$ and $E_2$. But something is fishy in the problem statement, because if $\hat{e_1}$ and $\hat{e_2}$ are the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $\cos(\phi)=\cos(\pi/2)=0$.

Comment: You sir are fitting of your user name.

Comment: I believe the $\phi=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a consequence of the electric field of the plane waves being polarised.

On the understanding the $\phi$ is the relative phase between two phases:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/polclas.html

Comment: Hm I suppose that makes sense. Still if hypothetically they were in the same direction, or they both had a component in each direction, could we show that $\phi=\phi_1-\phi_2$?